# c++ fstream changing space in file

Tags: c++, space, fstream

I would like to change in my file "ok.txt" every 2 space into one.
That is my code.

```
fstream file1("ok.txt",ios::in|ios::out);

    if (file1.is_open())
    {
        cout << Acces allowed" << endl;

        string c;
        getline(file1, c);

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++)
        {
            if (c[i] == '  ')
                c[i] = ' ';
        }

        file1 << c;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error";
    }
    file1.close();
```

Comment: And what is your question? what problems are you having?

Comment: `'  '` (2 spaces) isn't a valid char literal.

Comment: i think yes , but how to manage with it ?

Comment: I think what you meant is `if(c[i] == ' ' && c[i+1] == ' ')`

Comment: @igaar Take care, that could easily access out of bounds.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ True, but not so _If one knows what they are doing._ **It could  simply be avoided by** `for(int i = 0; i < c.length() - 1; i++)`

Comment: @igaar `i < c.length() - 1;` is also wrong, that leaves the last character unhandled.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ By the way `for(int i = 0; i < c.length() - 1; i++)`  won't leave the last character unhanded since `if(c[i] == ' ' && c[i+1] == ' ')` will always compare the two last characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use as a replace algorithm, something like this:

```
std::string s = "bla  bla  bla";
std::string onespace = " ";
std::string doublespace = "  ";

size_t start_pos = 0;
while(( start_pos = s.find(doublespace, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
     s.replace(start_pos, doublespace.length(), onespace);
     start_pos += onespace.length();
}
```

This will transform `s` in `bla bla bla`

Answer (score 2):

replace it:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++)
    {
        if (c[i] == '  ')
            c[i] = ' ';
    }
```

with:

```
string singleSpace=" ";
string doubleSpace="  ";
int position = c.find( doubleSpace ); 
while ( position != string::npos ) 
{
  c.replace( position, doubleSpace.length(), singleSpace );
  position = c.find(doubleSpace, position + 1 );
}
```

Note that double space is a string not a single character.